# Restricting Variable Domain without CLPFD Library

Tags: prolog, sudoku, clpfd

I have a list of variables in my program, say A, B, C, D, ..., J, and I need to restrict the domain of each of the variables to the same set of integers, say 1, 2, ... 10.  I know of a few different ways to do this, but all of them use at least one method from CLPFD, such as `X #> 0`, `X ins [domain]`, or `fd_domain(args)`.  I haven't been able to find a way of doing this without any built-in libraries (all of which are banned for this project).

I would think that writing in the rules like this would be sufficient:

```
A > 0, A < 11, B > 0, B < 11, ..., J > 0, J < 11
```

But apparently the variables are not sufficiently instantiated.  I know it's a trivially simple question, but I've been searching on my own for a while and really have no other resources for help.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the `between` function in SWI-Prolog:

```
?- between(1, 9, A).
A = 1 ;
A = 2 ;
A = 3 ;
A = 4 ;
A = 5 ;
A = 6 ;
A = 7 ;
A = 8 ;
A = 9.
```

If that's banned as well (it's non-standard), then you use `member/2`:

```
?- member(A, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]).
A = 1 ;
A = 2 ;
A = 3 ;
A = 4 ;
A = 5 ;
A = 6 ;
A = 7 ;
A = 8 ;
A = 9.
```

Without CLP(fd), you'll be trapped in the generate-and-test paradigm, though, and perhaps it's better to find some workaround where you check variable values in an ad hoc way to get decent performance.

Comment: Thank you SO much, this is exactly what I've been looking for.  I really don't know why I had such a difficult time finding it; I guess people prefer to just rely on CLPFD since it's so thorough in a lot of ways.  Anyway, I appreciate your help immensely.